# Estimating the expectation of a random variable with a continuous distribution by a sum

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am reading a proof on subguassian tails and I am confused by the estimation I just read, can anyone explain how it makes sense?

Let F be the distribution function of the random variable X. What the proof is calculating is $ \mathbb{E} [e^{uX}] = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{ut} dF(t) $. First, the proof separates this calculation from $- \infty$ to $\frac{1}{u}$ and from $\frac{1}{u}$ to $\infty$. I have problems with the latter part.

$$ \int_{\frac{1}{u}}^{\infty} e^{ut} dF(t) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{k+1} \operatorname{Prob}\left[X \geq \frac{k}{u} \right] \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{2k}e^{-ak^2/u^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{k(2-ak/u^2)}$$.

I don't understand the less than approximation happening at $ \int_{\frac{1}{u}}^{\infty} e^{ut} dF(t) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{k+1} \operatorname{Prob}[X \geq \frac{k}{u}] $. How does that make sense?

Comment: thanks for the tip @joriki, I edited my question, hope it looks a little more readable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This treats the integral as a sum of the integrals over the intervals $\left[\frac ku,\frac{k+1}u\right]$, bounds the integrand in each interval by its value at the upper endpoint of the interval and bounds the measure of each interval by the entire remaining measure up to $\infty$.

Comment: That's what I considered, as well but I don't understand how the measure dF(t) is somewhat approximated by $\operatorname{Prob}\left[X \geq \frac{k}{u}\right]$. So normally what it's supposed to be is $\operatorname{Prob} [\frac{k}{u} \leq X \leq \frac{k+1}{u}]$ right? So, is it taking a very big estimate?

Comment: @diane: 

$$
\int_a^b\mathrm e^{ut}\mathrm dF(t)\le\int_a^b\mathrm e^{ub}\mathrm dF(t)=\mathrm e^{ub}\int_a^b\mathrm dF(t)\le\mathrm e^{ub}\int_a^\infty\mathrm dF(t)=\mathrm e^{ub}\operatorname{Prob}\left[X\ge a\right]\;.
$$

Comment: I see it now, thank you!